# How can I call a function independently on each element in a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, handlebars.js

For each element in my database, I am creating a separate thumbnail to display. I have a dropdown menu, and depending on the user's selection I want to show a different form using a function, but the function only works on the first element in the page. When I make a selection on the second, third element, the selection affects the first element and not its corresponding element. How can I solve this such that when I make a selection on the first element, it affects the first element, a selection on the second element affects the second element and so on? My code looks something like this at the moment (in the example below the elements are hard-coded, but in my actual code the elements come from a database and are displayed in a loop):

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <h1>First element</h1>
        <label for="type">Make a selection:</label>
        <select id="tipo" onchange="choose(this);">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
            <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <div class="thumbnail hidden" id="option1">
            <h3>This is option 1</h3>
            <form action='/option1' method="POST">
                <input name="number" type="number" required>
                <input name="text" type="text" required>
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail hidden" id="option2">
            <h3>This is option 2</h3>
            <form action='/option2' method="POST">
                <input name="number" type="number" required>
                <input name="text" type="text" required>
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <h1>Second element</h1>
        <label for="type">Make a selection:</label>
        <select id="tipo" onchange="choose(this);">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
            <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <div class="thumbnail hidden" id="option1">
            <h3>This is option 1</h3>
            <form action='/option1' method="POST">
                <input name="number" type="number" required>
                <input name="text" type="text" required>
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail hidden" id="option2">
            <h3>This is option 2</h3>
            <form action='/option2' method="POST">
                <input name="number" type="number" required>
                <input name="text" type="text" required>
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function choose(that) {
    if (that.value == "option1") {
        document.getElementById("option1").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("option2").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("option1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("option2").style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

I already tried using a jquery each() loop but to no avail. I tried jquery by adding a class to the parent div in each element, and wrapping my current function in a `$('.newClass').each(function choose(that){...});`.
I also tried getting all the elements with the new class in the parent div, and then looping through them and calling the current function in each iteration but that didn't work. Something like:`let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.newClass');` and then `for(let i = 0; ...){function choose(that){...}}`.
I have also tried not using loops, but instead, use jquery to get the next element of a certain class, and use classes instead of ids in my code. I think this is the best approach but I cannot get it to work. My new function that uses classes instead of ids looks like:

```
function choose(that) {
    if (that.value == "option1") {
        $(this).closest('.option1').style.display = "block";;
        $(this).closest('.option2').style.display = "none";
    } else {
        $(this).closest('.option1').style.display = "none";
        $(this).closest('.option2').style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Please help, how can I get this to work?

Comment: What is your currentFunction() doing actually?

Comment: Use $('.newClass').each(currentFunction); just remove the parenthesis following the function name.

Comment: You've probably already accounted for this, but just in case: The behavior you described also sounds like what you'd get it the dropdown functionality weren't returning the second item correctly.

Comment: jQuery uses `$(this).closest('.option1').css('display', 'block');` or `$(this).closest('.option1').css({display:'block'});`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was duplicated `id` attributes. What I've done was prefixing them based on the `section-name`:

- `first-section-option1`
- `first-section-option2`
- `second-section-option1`
- `second-section-option2`

and used [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#Syntax), targeting sibling with `id` ending with desired option index:

```
[id$="option1"]
```

I also prefixed the select's `id` attributes, but it's irrelevant.

Working example below:

```js
function choose(that) {
    var $select = $(that);
    if (that.value == "option1") {
        $select.siblings('[id$=option1]').show();
        $select.siblings('[id$=option2]').hide();
    } else {
        $select.siblings('[id$=option2]').show();
        $select.siblings('[id$=option1]').hide();
    }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <h1>First element</h1>
        <label for="first-element-tipo">Make a selection:</label>
        <select id="first-element-tipo" onchange="choose(this);">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
            <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <div class="thumbnail hidden" id="first-element-option1">
            <h3>This is option 1</h3>
            <form action='/option1' method="POST">
                <input name="number" type="number" required>
                <input name="text" type="text" required>
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail hidden" id="first-element-option2">
            <h3>This is option 2</h3>
            <form action='/option2' method="POST">
                <input name="number" type="number" required>
                <input name="text" type="text" required>
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <h1>Second element</h1>
        <label for="second-element-tipo">Make a selection:</label>
        <select id="second-element-tipo" onchange="choose(this);">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
            <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <div class="thumbnail hidden" id="second-element-option1">
            <h3>This is option 1</h3>
            <form action='/option1' method="POST">
                <input name="number" type="number" required>
                <input name="text" type="text" required>
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail hidden" id="second-element-option2">
            <h3>This is option 2</h3>
            <form action='/option2' method="POST">
                <input name="number" type="number" required>
                <input name="text" type="text" required>
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Comment: Yup, this works perfect!!! Thanks a lot, this was a great help and I am sorry for the late reply.

Comment: No worries, happy to be help :)